# Sorting table output chronologically

Tags: r

I have a database of incidents by their date. I want to create a frequency table of incidents by month and year.

I am using this code below:

```
table(format(dat$Report.Date,"%m/%Y"))
```

> 01/2004 01/2005 01/2006 01/2007 01/2008 01/2009 01/2011 01/2012 01/2013 01/2014 ...

It doesn't sort chronologically. I tried sort() and order() and it did not work.
I want this output:

> 01/2004, 02/2004, 03/2004 ... 12/2004, 1/2005...

What should I do?

Comment: Use `format(dat$Report.Date,"%Y/%m")` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the `table`, extract the 'month' and `year` separetely and do the sorting on the sequence

```
tbl <- table(format(dat$Report.Date,"%m/%Y"))
v1 <- as.numeric(substr(names(tbl), 1, 2))
v2 <- as.numeric(substr(names(tbl), 4, 8))
tbl[order(v2, ave(seq_along(v1), v1, FUN = seq_along))]
```

---

Or another option is to convert to `yearmon` object and then do the sorting

```
library(zoo)
tbl[order(as.yearmon(names(tbl), "%m/%Y"))]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(Report.Date = sample(seq(as.Date('2008-01-01'), 
            length.out = 100, by = '1 month')))
```